# Build complete Distro with LFS

Tags: distributions, livecd, lfs

I want to build distro from source with LFS. Which include default third party tools & tools from different Linux distro. I have following questions:

1. Can I build with LFS?
2. Using LFS can I make Live CD which must run on any Intel/AMD(x64) or I can distribute to my friends and they can install on there PCs.
3. Is LFS good way to do this or any alternative?
4. Any hints and suggestion are welcome to do this stuff.

Comment: At a guess after trying to parse your question, I suspect LFS is the *worst* possible way to try to do what I think you have in mind.

Comment: @Shadur-It is worst then there is an alternative in your mind,as i mention above give suggestion to do that.

Answer (score 2):

[Beyond LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/) shows you how to add additional packages to LFS beyond the minimal installation. But LFS/BLFS doesn't really provide you a good way to build a Live CD.

Gentoo, another source-based distribution, has a [step-by-step guide for making a custom Gentoo-based Live CD/DVD](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Build_Your_Own_LiveCD_or_LiveDVD). If you want to build a custom source-based distribution this is probably your best starting point.